# Get Sublist of Java List, Without Creating a New List?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a list in Java, and I need to get a sublist of it. I am trying to avoid creating a new list and populating that, is it possible to create a list that is at the same point in memory, just shorter?

```java
double[] list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};

// later:
double[] list2 = list1[0:2] //?
```

In the example above, I want `list2` to be a sublist of 0 to 2 (`{1, 2}`).
Is this possible? Or should I switch to using ArrayLists `sublist` method? I am trying to avoid this.

I am trying to avoid ArrayLists, because I am using a library that requires an argument to be a `double[]` list.

Comment: Java is not Python, so that's not a list. It's an array. If you don't want to use (`Array`)`List`s, and you don't want to create a new array and populate that, I'm afraid you're out of options.

Comment: No, but you could implement one for read-only.  But if you want read and write but share structures, you will want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure

Comment: I suggest comments be at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77554313/get-sublist-of-java-list-without-creating-a-new-list , which was closed for being a duplicate of an already existing question with answers.  (This was closed because it is a duplicate of that question.)